# How to cut a raster with a polygon, but I'm interested in what remains after cutting?

Tags: qgis, raster

I am using QGIS 2.14.

What I have: A raster file and a polygon.
What I need to do: Cut the raster using the polygon.

Important: But I want to keep the remaining part of the raster from which the polygon has been cut. Basically, I want to make a hole on a raster, shaped like the polygon.

Comment: Interesting idea.  just a quick answer to your first question nothing actually happens to the raster, a new layer is created that is clipped to the extents of the polygon. as for creating a doughnut, perhaps look into raster calculator and adding a simple mask on top

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding some things... raster is a continous data layer (word-key: continous) you can't make holes in it like in vector (or am I wrong?)

Comment: Use gdal_rasterize and burn your polygon into the raster. Relevant old answers http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138369/cut-a-hole-into-a-geotiff/138371#138371 http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163371/reverse-gdal-rasterize-i-option-does-not-work/163524#163524 http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173308/how-to-invert-or-reverse-a-vector-cutline-when-gdalwarping-a-raster