# Clipping raster inside a polygon (making hole)

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdalwarp

Clipping a raster using a polygon with GDAL is easy - that is if you want to discard the data outside the polygon and keep what's inside it.
(Using gdalwarp -cutline)

I would like to discard what's inside the polygon and keep the outside (e.g. make a hole in my raster).

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: You could try making a big polygon, larger than the raster and cut the hole out. Every void that I've tried in GDAL/OGR has worked as expected so I would expect this to work too. Otherwise create two C polygons overlapping and cut twice.

Comment: You can't cut pixels from the middle of the raster but you can hide the area by painting the corresponding pixels with some other color. You will find answers from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219355/how-to-cut-a-raster-with-a-polygon-but-im-interested-in-what-remains-after-cut

Comment: I edited the answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163371/reverse-gdal-rasterize-i-option-does-not-work by adding the result of the standard operation with non-inverted vector mask.

Comment: @user30184 thanks for your answer, but 'hiding pixels' with another layer on top is not what I'm looking for.  My purpose is to assign 'null' values to a part or the raster (in a simple way, making a hole in it).  Very simple in Mapinfo Discover.  It would be great to have the option in GDAL and QGIS (with a simple command line option like -cropinside); hopefully some day it will exist.

Comment: Gdal_rasterize does not create another layer. It is really changing the pixel values of the raster image permanently. You can set the new pixels to any value you want. In your case use you should use the nodata value of your image. Gdal_rasterize is your tool, please try it.

Comment: I wonder if you did not notice that gdal_rasterize can update an existing image even it can also create a new image as a target.

Answer (score 1):

@Michael Miles-Stimson thanks for your answer.  I was checking if anybody knew an efficient way to do it (without the need to edit polygons, etc).  It looks like Mapinfo Discover is still more efficient than GDAL for this task.

[image: Clipping inside polygon in Encom Discover]

Comment: For this purpose GDAL has a special tool http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html.